# ASP.NET Core WebApi wwwroot folder marked as ignored

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

It's time to learn ASP.NET Core, so I create test project. When I learn project structure I found then folder for static files (wwwroot) marked as ignored.
StaticFiles package was added as well as UseStaticFiles method was called on Configure. Why this happend? How should I fix tis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you will add static files inside the folder, it will no longer be ignored by your Source Control Manager.